# How to fix the size of the div to print on a4 size paper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have a div of size 400*400px. I wrote a function to print it as follows

```
 function CallPrint(strid) {
        var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
        var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=400px,height=400px,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
        WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
        WinPrint.document.close();
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
    }
```

This prints the content on whole a4 size paper. How can i fix the size of the hard copy printout.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a print stylesheet.
http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml